# Showing data from a mysql table grouped by the month

Tags: php, mysql, select

Basically I have a lot of data in a table and its creation date with it. I want to show all of the data from the table, however in its output it need to be in date order, and then with a heading of the month it was created in above it.

i.e.

**January**
data1
data2
data3

**February**
data4
data5

**March**
data6
data7
data8
data9

Is this possible from one query? I'm using php and mysql.

Thanks

Table Layout will be something like:

```
ID | Type | Content | User | Colour | Creation Date
```

It's all theory at the moment, but I will be creating it later today and tomorrow. I just needed to know if it's possible.

Comment: What's the table layout?

Comment: Yes, but it would help to see your table definition. Could you edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simply add the month to the query, order the query by date, and then track the month during the output phase and insert a new heading every time the month changes:

```
SELECT *, MONTH(thedate) AS month FROM thetable ORDER BY thedate;
```

In the PHP:

```
$lastmonth = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult))
{
  if (empty($lastmonth)) { $lastmonth = $row['month']; }

  if ($lastmonth != $row['month'])
  {
    $lastmonth = $row['month'];
    // print new month header
  }

  // print row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = mysql_query( 'SELECT MONTHNAME(creation_date) AS month_name, data_name
                     FROM my_table ORDER BY creation_date' );
$currentMonth = null;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    if( $currentMonth !== $row['month_name'] ) {
        echo '<h1>'.$row['month_name'].'</h1>';
        $currentMonth = $row['month_name'];
    }
    echo '<p>'.$row['data_name'].'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a MONTH column to your schema and populate it from the creation date.  You need two columns to do this.

It sounds more like a reporting function than something that's transactional.  The solution would be easy if you off-loaded historical records from your OLAP database into a reporting star schema with a time dimension.  It would cut down on the size of your OLAP data set as well.